# Using EGit and GitLab for multiple projects

Tags: java, eclipse, git, gitlab, egit

I have started using EGit with Eclipse Oxygen and GitLab today. I have two projects and two different repositories on GitLab. However I'm unsure how to properly connect each project to its repository. In Eclipse > Settings > Git > Configuration > Repository Settings I have managed to set one url in remote > origin > url. But I have no idea how to set a different url for the other project.

I have the first project successfully uploaded to GitLab now, but GitLab shows the files under `Desktop/some/other/path/MyProject`, where my project is located on my computer, but I want GitLab to just show all files and the src folder on the "main" page. How do I tell it to do that?

I have been googling for quite a while and looked at some EGit tutorials but I couldn't find out how to do this. I'm a newbie to this stuff, so I'd appreciate some explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that each of your project has its own .git subfolder in it.

```
cd /path/to/project1
git init .
git remote add origin https://github.com/<me>/project1

cd /path/to/project2
git init .
git remote add origin https://github.com/<me>/project2
```

Then you can import those two projects in your Eclipse workspace and use [Team Share](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Sharing) on each imported project: Eclipse will recognize the *existing* Git repo and their remote origin URL automatically

Comment: Done that, but for some reason it's not pushing the code in the Eclipse project to the repository on GitLab.

Comment: @Priv That is for importing only, not for pushing. You need to make new commits in order to push (and I used github.com URLs: replace them by your remote GitLab URL)

Comment: @Priv Once you have the git init . done in the right folder, and done a few commits locally, you can try a git push -u origin master. If that works (from the command line), then you can try it from EGit (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Upstream)

Comment: ` ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/..../.....git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: @Priv That happens if your remote repo was not empty (typically a readme): try a `git pull origin master` first, then `git push -u origin master`. If this works, you can go back to EGit.